# Collection not supported in Layer.php

Tags: php, magento

I have written a magento query,

```
 $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->addOrderedQty($from, $to)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
        $productCollection->getSelect()->limit( $limit );
```

This works perfectly and gives me required result, but when used in Catalog/Model/Layer.php, I'm getting an error. I think it supports only Mage::getModel('catalog/product')

How to rewrite this query and make it work in Layer.php. Any help would be great.

Comment: what error are you getting in Layer.php?

Comment: call to member function getId() on a non object

Comment: Seems like you are looking for error in the wrong place; there is no any "getId()" call in the code you provided. There is line number specified in fatal error message, check Layer.php for that line.